# 405 Not Allowed on AJAX Call

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, http-status-code-405

I am trying to make a simple contact form using PHP and AJAX. When called directly (via `action="sendmail.php"`), the php form works fine, however when i try to do it with jquery AJAX i receive 405 Not Allowed.

Now the console returns:

```
n.ajaxTransport.k.cors.a.crossDomain.send @ code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4
n.extend.ajax                             @ code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4
n.each.n.(anonymous function)             @ code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:4
n.event.dispatch                          @ code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3
n.event.add.r.handle                      @ code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js:3

(anonymous function)                      @ contact.html:187
```

This seems to suggest a cross domain request, except it's not. The file is domain.com/contact.html, and the php document is domain.com/sendmail.php.

Here is the original request (aka the "anonymous function" on line 187)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $('#submit').click(function() {
          $.post("./sendmail.php", $("#contactform").serialize(), function(data){}); 
          //line 187 ^^^
            $('#success').html('<br>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;Message sent!<br><br>');
            $('#success').hide(2000);
        });
    });
```

and sendmail.php (Edit: I did try turning on error reporting here and got no errors)

```
<?php
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$regarding = $_POST['regarding'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

$to = 'myemail@domain.com';
$subject = 'Contact Form';
$message = $name." would like to be contacted regarding " .$regarding. ". " .$name. " can be reached via email at ".$email." or via phone at " .$phone. ".\r\n\r\n S/he also provided the following comments: ".$comments. ".";
$headers = 'From: phpmailer@domain.com';

$mail=mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
if($mail){
    echo "1"; //success
}
else{
    echo "0"; //failed
}
?>
```

any help would be appreciated. would also be interested to know why this doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: @Tomanow if the files are in the same path, `./` would be perfectly fine. On topic, do you have any headers being sent by php that denies access in some way? Open developer tools and view the ajax request in the network tab. Look at the request/response headers to see what they are.

Comment: Log from your http server (running php) will help other people help you.

Comment: Add error reporting to the top of your file(s) right after your opening PHP tag for example `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1); `then the rest of your code, to see if it yields anything.

Comment: Usually the `406 Method Not Allowed` error is the result of making a request to the page in a method that it is not setup to handle. And by method, I mean `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `DELETE`...etc. You omitted the word "method" which is important here. By default the pages are setup (in apache I mean) to accept `GET` and `POST` requests. This is likely a server configuration issue and not a cross site issue.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn i dont have an ajax tab. i have only XHR, Script, Style, Images, Media, Fonts, Documents, WebSockets, Other.

Comment: @xiamx there are no errors in the log. i just created a fresh vps to run this on to see if the error was in the configuration on the live server but i experienced the same result.

Comment: @PedroLobito NO errors there. i did try that, just forgot to mention in the post.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Id be inclined to agree, except even stock configuration doesn't allow this to work. I am using Nginx not apache but i even tested on IIS via a VM and got the same result there.

Comment: Well, that is what the error means. The method you are trying to access the server with is not allowed. Are you using any sort of framework or routing? Because those seem to be common places of issues. However, if the page was working when submitting a form via post, then it should work. The server doesn't know the difference between a standard page load and an ajax request.

Comment: It is a post method and I agree that it should work. It works perfectly when called normally but yet this happens when called via ajax. I am not using any frameworks

Comment: @Shanimal it doesn't matter. I'll eventually have it pass back secessor failure. That was just used for me to make sure the php was working while directly accessing the script. Eventually success or failure will trigger the message sent or a message failed notification... But that relies on me being able to get it working at all.

Comment: hmm. changing the form method from post to get works flawlessly now. that doesn't make a lot of sense to me, but i noticed in the headers it was saying "provisional headers provided" a little dig into this shows a lot of other people having this problem on chrome and modifying the headers in firefly from post to get gave me status 200.